# Writing Python arrays into txt file, one array per line

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to write a number of Python Arrays into a txt file, with one array per line. After which I would like to read the Arrays line by line.

My work in progress code below. The problem I am working on involves about 100,000 arrays (length of L)

```
from __future__ import division
from array import array

M = array('I',[1,2,3])
N = array('I',[10,20,30])

L = [M,N]

with open('manyArrays.txt','w') as file:
    for a in L:
        sA = a.tostring()
        file.write(sA + '\n')

with open('manyArrays.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:   
        lineRead = array('I', [])
        lineRead.fromstring(line)
        print MRead
```

The error message I get is

```
lineRead.fromstring(line)
ValueError: string length not a multiple of item size
```

Comment: `array.array` has a method called literally [`array.tostring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use numpy function for this, or code lines yourself:

You could concatenate your arrays in one 2D array and save it directly with np.savetxt, load it with np.genfromtext :

```
M = np.array([1,2,3],dtype='I')
N = np.array([10,20,30],dtype='I')
data= np.array([M,N])

file='test.txt'
np.savetxt(file,data)
M2,N2 = np.genfromtxt(file)
```

Or do :

```
file2='test2.txt'
form="%i %i %i \n"
with open(file2,'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        f.write(form % (data[i,0],data[i,1],data[i,2]))
```

Comment: `array.array` that OP use is _not_ `numpy.array`.

Comment: Indeed @ForceBru. While this is not clear in my post, the numpy solution still works with array.array elements. `np.savetxt('todel;txt',L)` and `M2,N2 = np.genfromtxt(file)` will yield the wanted result. 
For the classical way you would just change the indexing with [i][k] :
`file2='test2.txt'
form="%i %i %i \n"
with open(file2,'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        f.write(form % (data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2]))`